VScode Terminals and Jupyter Freeze when calling functions that open a window
I have multiple functions that when called, VSCode terminals and jupyter will get stuck and never execute. Here's an example:
def get_file_path(filetype, filepath=''):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    if not filepath:
        filepath = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[(filetype[0], ''.join(['*', filetype[1]]))])
    path_dir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    common_string = os.path.basename(filepath)
    common_string = common_string[0:-4] 
    return filepath, path_dir, common_string

if I call the function from the terminal get_file_path(['HDF5 file', '.h5']) it will start the function and get stuck on the line where tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() is called.
I've noticed it seems to be functions that open a window are causing the freezes, so I have a theory that VSCode thinks the window opened and is waiting for me to select a file on the window that never appeared, however matplotlib.pyplot.show() will also freeze (this only happens when calling .plot() from the debug console, plotting works fine when in the interactive window). It opens the window, but the plots don't show and the windows "python is not responding" message will eventually come up, which doesn't seem to match the theory.
I don't get any errors, it just seems to be stuck/frozen. Jupyter will sometimes give a timeout, but the terminals just spin for eternity.
The issue only occurs in the VSCode Jupyter notebooks and integrated/debugging/interactive terminals. Everything works fine if I call these functions from an external terminal or run them in a script with the VScode debugger or interactive window.

Does the terminal unfreeze when all windows called in this way have been closed?

@AdamJ754 Except for pyplot.plot()/show() no windows open in the first place. If I close the unresponsive matplotlib windows it actually ends the debug session.
The pyplot freezing only happens in the debugger, not the interactive window. I updated the post to mention this.
